# MySQL - SQL length question

Tags: mysql

What is the correct SQL statement for

SELECT kw where length(kw) > 3
FROM data group by kw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-order the query and use the [CHAR_LENGTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) function:

```
SELECT kw FROM data WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(kw) > 3 GROUP BY kw;
```

It should be noted that using functions in the WHERE clause is frowned upon as the function is executed for every row of the `data` table.

If you are not restricted by disk space, consider re-architecting your solution so you can store the required information in another column (in this case, store the length of `kw` in a `kw_length`). This will speed the query up and save unnecessary processor cycles.

Comment: The OP might _want_ the byte-length instead of char-length (the table is called data after all...).